# Java - the function in case of an exit from the program

Tags: java

I have the main program which transfers files for the composer of diagrams, and opens it. If I close the composer of diagrams and I open composer of diagrams with new files from the main program, there can be errors because in case of the first exit from the graphic composer some important variables aren't nullified.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit and add relevant part of your code

Comment: Sounds like the separation between the components is not very clean. Most likely you keep some data related to the composer in the main program. If all the relevant variables are kept in the composer then they get initialized with the new instance. *Unless* they are `static`, in which case they're common to all instances - avoid that.

Comment: @kiheru yes, problem was in your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)` is what you are looking for. There you can handle shutdown signal of your program.